# Reduce constructor boilerplate code in class hierarchy

Tags: c++11, constructor

In our code with have a class hierarchy with virtual functions. We have different
“diagrams” which produce a fixed bunch of numbers based on the same sort of parameters.
The details are different, but the behavior is the same.

We are happy with the dynamic polymorphism as a pattern, we are not so fond of all the
boilerplate code that we have to write in C++11 in order to achieve it. Mostly I am
frustrated by the repetition in the constructors.

The class hierarchy looks as follows:

[image]

There is one base, two intermediate and a lot of children. The base and the intermediate
have non-trivial constructors, the children do not require any more parameters. Yet we
have to produce a constructor in the children because the default constructor would not
properly construct the intermediate.

This is the code, stripped down to constructors, destructors and members only. The
`Diagram` class:

```
class Diagram {
public:
  Diagram(std::vector<CorrInfo> const &corr_lookup)
      : corr_lookup_(corr_lookup) {}

  virtual ~Diagram() {}

private:
  std::vector<CorrInfo> const &corr_lookup_;
};
```

The intermediate `DiagramNumeric<>` class:

```
template <typename Numeric_>
class DiagramNumeric : public Diagram {
public:
  using Numeric = Numeric_;

  DiagramNumeric(std::vector<CorrInfo> const &_corr_lookup,
                 std::string const &output_path,
                 std::string const &output_filename,
                 int const Lt)
      : Diagram(_corr_lookup),
        output_path_(output_path),
        output_filename_(output_filename),
        Lt_(Lt),
        correlator_(corr_lookup().size(), std::vector<Numeric>(Lt, Numeric{})),
        c_(omp_get_max_threads(),
           std::vector<std::vector<Numeric>>(
               Lt, std::vector<Numeric>(corr_lookup().size(), Numeric{}))) {}

private:
  std::string const &output_path_;
  std::string const &output_filename_;

  int const Lt_;

  std::vector<std::vector<Numeric>> correlator_;
  std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<Numeric>>> c_;
};
```

And one of the children, here `C2c`:

```
class C2c : public DiagramNumeric<cmplx> {
public:
  C2c(std::vector<CorrInfo> const &corr_lookup,
      std::string const &output_path,
      std::string const &output_filename,
      int const Lt);
};

C2c::C2c(std::vector<CorrInfo> const &corr_lookup,
         std::string const &output_path,
         std::string const &output_filename,
         int const Lt)
    : DiagramNumeric<cmplx>(corr_lookup, output_path, output_filename, Lt) {}
```

When I need to add another argument to the constructor of the intermediate, I have to
change the `DiagramNumeric<>` declaration, and *every* child declaration and definition.
This makes `2 * N + 1` changes with `N` children and feels awful.

I thought about making a `struct` as `DiagramNumeric<>::CtorParams` and that is just
passed through. The client code where the `C2c` is instantiated needs to be adapted, but
we actually pass only different `corr_lookup` parameters, the remaining three are always
the same.

Is there some mechanism with which we can cut away a significant portion of this
boilerplate code?

Comment: As `C2c` doesn't have any additional constructor params, `using DiagramNumeric::DiagramNumeric`. Aside: why `int Lt;` instead of `Numeric_ Lt;` ?

Comment: Thank you, that `using` already cuts down on a lot of code! --- The `Lt` is the number of slices in the time direction, whereas `Numeric_` is the result type like `std::complex<double>`. Therefore `Numeric_ Lt` is not applicable in this context.

Comment: `The details are different, but the behavior is different.` you meant but the behavior is the same, right ?

Comment: @UmNyobe: Yes indeed, I have fixed it. Thanks for spotting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We are happy with the dynamic polymorphism as a pattern,.... I am
>   frustrated by the repetition in the constructors.

This isn't some c++11 fault. The **issue come directly from dynamic polymorphism**. And particularly from the fact that each child class is required to construct its parents.

The alternative you have is dependency injection + static polymorphism :

1. You have classes and methods taking a `Diagram` template as argument
2. You don't have a Diagram class anymore ***(static polymorphism)***
3. C2c and the other classes don't construct a `DiagramNumeric<cmplx>` anymore, but merely receive one as argument which is copied to a member variable. (***dependency injection***)

You will end up with

```
class C2c {
public:
  explicit C2c(const DiagramNumeric<cmplx> &diagram_numeric) 
  : diagram_numeric_(diagram_numeric) {}

private :
   DiagramNumeric<cmplx> diagram_numeric_;
};
```

Let say you want to add another argument. In the best case, that's a O(1) change in terms of dependent classes. In the worst case, it's back to 2*N+1 changes if you have a builder function such as

```
C2c build(std::vector<CorrInfo> const &corr_lookup,
      std::string const &output_path,
      std::string const &output_filename,
      int const Lt)
{
    return C2c(DiagramNumeric<cmplx>(corr_lookup, output_path, output_filename, Lt));
}
```

Comment: Is there some alternative in static polymorphism to the construct `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Diagram>> diagrams; for (auto const &diagram : diagrams) diagram->build();`? We were planning to extend this to a `std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Diagram>>` to build the diagrams selected in the parameter file. With static polymorphism I don't see how we can easily do this.

Comment: Until a few weeks ago I had the feeling that you answer does not really solve my problem. And in the past weeks we have thrown out the class hierarchy altogether and encoded the difference in behavior completely in some data structure. This way we solved all the boilerplate problems at once. In the end, your answer has been correct all along, but I did not see it yet!